# Replace ViewController via Button, Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to replace my `UITableViewController` by an `ViewController` with a `UITableView` inside. For this I use following code:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VcId") as! JobTableViewController
    self.navigationController?.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But I get this Error all the time on the second line

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Upload your demo to github

Comment: Add guard check to make sure storyboard actually instantiated your VC or it returned nil

Comment: Got it working with following code:  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this :

```
guard let newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VcId") as? JobTableViewController else {return}
self.navigationController?.present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)}
```

The error may be occuring because the viewcontroller may not be found in the storyboard , you may have given the wrong ID.